# Vagrant: undefined method 'box_url='

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am attempting to setup a basic Vagrant instance based off of a Jeffery Way tutorial.  I am getting this error when I run vagrant up:

```
../Vagrantfile:9:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `box_url=' for "precise32":String (NoMethodError)
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:574:in `new'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:574:in `vagrantfile'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:359:in `host'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:168:in `block in action_runner'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:346:in `hook'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:556:in `unload'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/bin/vagrant:169:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/bin/vagrant:169:in `<main>'
```

The only things I have done thus far are run vagrant init and 
Modified the 'Vagrantfile' to look like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.box.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

end
```

Google is not turning anything up about an "undefined method 'box_url='" ... any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax! It needs to be like this

```
config.vm.box = "precise32"
config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
```